# Фильтрация QTreeView с QSortFilterProxyModel

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt5

Есть дерево вида:

Нода1

--Нода2

----Нода3   Значение1  Значение2

----Нода4   Значение3  Значение4

И так далее...

(Внешний вид дерева в прикрепленном файле)
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Мне надо отфильтровать модель по различающимся значениям в одной строке.
То есть, если Значение1 совпадает (равно) со Значением2, то эту строку пропускаем, если нет - выводим.

Есть пример кода:

```
class FindFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
        if (self.filterAcceptsRowItself(source_row, source_parent)):
            return True

        if (self.hasAcceptedChildren(source_row, source_parent)):
            return True

        return False

    def filterAcceptsRowItself(self, source_row, source_parent):
        return super(FindFilterProxyModel, self).\
        filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)

    def hasAcceptedChildren(self, source_row, source_parent):
        model = self.sourceModel()
        sourceIndex = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)
        if not (sourceIndex.isValid()):
            return False

        childCount = model.rowCount(sourceIndex)
        if (childCount == 0):
            return False

        for i in range (childCount): 
            if (self.filterAcceptsRowItself(i, sourceIndex)):
                return True
            if (self.hasAcceptedChildren(i, sourceIndex)):
                return True

        return False
```

Он рекурсивно сравнивает значения в первом столбце (использую для поиска).
А мне требуется, чтобы сравнение шло по всем столбцам, кроме первого.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть это поможет кому-то ещё. Данный код сравнивает значения в двух столбцах.

```
class DiffFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
def filterAcceptsRow(self, source_row, source_parent):
    # проверим, что моделька валидная
    # model = self.sourceModel()
    # if model is None:
    #     return False

    # index для первого столбца проверяемой строки
    src_index = model.index(source_row, 0, source_parent)

    # рекурсивно пробежимся по дереву
    for i in range (model.rowCount(src_index)):
        child_index = src_index.child(i, 0)
        c1 = child_index.sibling(child_index.row(), 1).data()
        c2 = child_index.sibling(child_index.row(), 2).data()

        # если есть хоть один потомок, удовлетворяющий условиям фильтра - ок!
        if (c1 != c2 or self.filterAcceptsRow(i, src_index)):
            return super(DiffFilterProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)                                                   
    # если потомки не отфильтрованы, проверим себя
    c1 = src_index.sibling(src_index.row(), 1).data()
    c2 = src_index.sibling(src_index.row(), 2).data()

    return c1 != c2 and super(DiffFilterProxyModel, self).filterAcceptsRow(source_row, source_parent)
```

Спасибо grondek за помощь.